# onVerificationCompleted does not work and firebase

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

for authentication through the cell phone number in firebase and android studio
The onVerificationCompleted method is not executed, which cannot get the verification code:

```
PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks callbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
    @Override
    public void onVerificationCompleted(@NonNull PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) 
    {//does not run on method calls

        String credential = phoneAuthCredential.getSmsCode();
        if(credential !=null){
            verification.setText(credential);
            sigIn(credential);
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(VerificationActivity.this,"Rechazado",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onVerificationFailed(@NonNull FirebaseException e) {
        Toast.makeText(VerificationActivity.this,"fallida",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCodeSent(@NonNull String s, @NonNull 
            PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
        super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);
        Toast.makeText(VerificationActivity.this,"codigo enviado",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Id = s;
    }
};
```

> Can you tell me what may be happening? and a solution, please and
> thank you in advance

Comment: Did you implement the variable `callback`?

Comment: @ Ticherhaz FreePalestine if like this: PhoneVerification.sendCodeVerification (phone, callbacks, activity)

Comment: Does `onVerficiationFailed` triggered?

Comment: @Ticherhaz FreePalestina if correct it is activated: onVerificationFailed (FirebaseException e) {} and void onCodeSent ( String s,PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {};